# std::function arguments list and typedefs

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a typedef something like that:

```
typedef std::function<int arg1, float arg2> MyFunction;
```

And somewhere in my code it is used like that:

```
MyFunction func = [](int arg1, float arg2){ /* do someting */ };
```

The thing is that every time I change the number of arguments of the function (for example I'm adding third argument char arg3) - I am forced to update it errywhere all over my code where I used MyFunction (even if these arguments are not used at all.

And I'm too lazy to do that. Is there any way to get arguments list of std::function from it's type?? (I mean ) so that function creation could look like that?:

```
MyFunction func = [](MyFunction::args){ /* do someting */ };
```

Comment: Use [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)?

Comment: @NathanOliver Argument number won't change automatically.

Comment: Adding new arguments will results in changing the body code. That meas you have to pass through all of them and chang the body. So, it will not hurt that much to change the the arguments. Anyway, find and replace is a solution also.

Comment: Have a single struct as an argument type

Comment: Having functions with unused arguments is a code smell.

Comment: Just a warning, the template parameters for `std::function` have the return type. `std::function<ReturnType(Arg1, Arg2)>`.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++14, you can use a variadic polymorphic lambda:

```
MyFunction func = [](int arg1, float arg2, auto&&... unused){ /* ... */ };
```

This will convert to `std::function<Sig>` for any signature beginning `int, float`.